# Issue with redirect when trying to define multiple optional parameters for Angular routes

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble defining multiple optional parameters for my Angular routes.

I want the following behavior:

- `/explorer` -> redirect to default `/explorer/camera`
- `/explorer/:itemType` -> `ExplorerComponent` (which will read `:itemType` e.g. as `camera`
- `/explorer/:itemType/:itemId` -> `ExplorerComponent` again, which will read the `:itemId` too

```
{
  path: "explorer",
  children: [
    {
      path: "",
      redirectTo: "camera"
    },
    {
      path: ":itemType/:itemId",
      pathMatch: "full",
      component: ExplorerComponent
    },
    {
      path: ":itemType",
      pathMatch: "full",
      component: ExplorerComponent
    }
  ]
}
```

but there is an issue:

- `/explorer` redirects to `/explorer/camera` as expected
- `/explorer/camera` redirects to `/explorer/camera/camera`
- `/explorer/camera/1` works as expected

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think if you add a pathMatch: "full" to the first child, it should work.

Comment: Thank you, that did it.